# apply function to class instance in place and not in place

Tags: python, class, oop, copy

I have a class with data attribute `dd`.
This class has a function member `my_fun`, which modifies the values of the internal `dd` of an instance using an helper method `baz()`.
I would like to have te possibility of performing that inplace i.e. on the same object and non inplace i.e. returning a new object and leave the original intact.
I have tried the following.
What is the right way to do that, possibly without having to `deepcopy`?

```
class myBar:
    def my_fun(self,params,inplace=True):
        if inplace:
            self.dd = baz(self.dd)
            return None
        else:
            copied_self=copy.deepcopy(self)
            copied_self.dd  =  baz(self.dd)
            return copied_self
```

Comment: So what is `if True`? Does it have any meaning?

Comment: Why do u want that without deeepcopy function?

Comment: In this MVE, if True replaces an actual complex boolean condition on each element of dd. Please consider that as a replacement for something more complicated

Comment: I have now edited for clarity

Comment: well, even with deepcopy, is this a reasonable approach?